# How can I know the values of: $\sin(i)$ and $\cos(i)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

> How can I know the values of: $\sin(i)$ and $\cos(i)$?

I am studying complex variables for the first time, so I asked myself if these functions exist (considering that the complex plane can be seen as $\mathbb{R}^2$); and, if so, how can I calculate their values?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you define $\sin$ and $\cos$ as

$$\sin z = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i};\quad \cos z = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}?$$

Comment: Ohhh Ok :), and If  I want to calculate the tangent, then I have to divide the formula of the sine between that of the cosine?

Answer (score 3):

In Complex Analysis, we define$$\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\cdots\text{ and }\cos z=1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\cdots$$In particular\begin{align}\sin i&=i-\frac{i^3}{3!}+\frac{i^5}{5!}-\cdots\\&=i\times\left(1+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{5!}+\cdots\right)\\&=\sinh(1)i.\end{align}By a similar argument, $\cos i=\cosh1$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall that

$$\cos z = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2} \implies \cos i = \frac{e^{-1}+e^{1}}{2}$$

and similarly for $\sin z$.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the definitions:
$$ \sin z=\frac{\mathrm e^{iz}-\mathrm e^{-iz}}{2i},\quad \cos z=\frac{\mathrm e^{iz}+\mathrm e^{-iz}}{2}.$$
Applying  these formulæ with $z=i$, we obtain 
$$\sin(i)=\frac{\mathrm e^{-1}-\mathrm e^{1}}{2i}=i\sinh(1),\qquad \cos(i)=\cosh(1).$$

Comment: And If I want to calculate the tangent, I  have to divide the sine and cosine as in $R$?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

- $\sin(i)=iG(\frac{i}{\pi})G(-\frac{i}{\pi})$ 
  and
- $\cos(i)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(i)},$

where

$\displaystyle G(z)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\big(1+\frac{z}{n}\big)e^{\frac{z}{n}},G$ is an entire function.